# How can I improve traction on an outdoor plywood ramp?

Tags: plywood

I've got a shed in a very shady area.  There's a plywood ramp from the ground (grass/dirt) to the shed door.

When it rains, the ramp gets slippery.  It stays slippery for a long time afterward, as it doesn't dry very quickly due to the shade (from trees).  I'm also concerned that the wood is starting to degrade from the moisture, although the shed itself seems fine.

What can I do to improve the traction on the ramp, and maybe to also protect it a little better from the moisture?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the best method is to use an anti slip tape / strip / paint

Tape

[image]

Strip

[image]

Paint

[image]

They are ordered form easiest to hardest.

The strips will be the easiest because you just stick them on. You will obviously stick them on the length where your tires will be going and not sideways (because that would be pointless). The strips are more durable, but don't be deceived by the stick on ones once they are stuck.. they are STUCK! The best, but most work is painting the whole ramp.

Preparation.

Needs to be a dry day for sticking on or painting. You need to clean the surface with paper towels - after you wiped the dirt away and the surface you want to stick/paint is dry you will use more paper towels and cheap alcohol (methanol, spirits, etc) - Using the alcohol cleans the surface and removes oil (so don't touch it after you wiped it). Clean it almost like waxing (several times the same spot), this will guarantee your surface is dirt free and guarantees best adhesion for years and years of life.

The strips you can just put down - but you need some cordless drill or elbow grease to get those screws in. Make sure they are flush (level with the strip) or you risk slashing your tires.

Here are some links

http://www.vubasupplies.co.uk/anti-slip-surfaces.html

http://www.anti-slip-paint.co.uk/

http://www.antislip.uk.com/antislip-decking-strip.html

Comment: I'd go for the paint. It's a little more work, but it will also help protect the wood from rot.

Comment: Beat me to it, good answer :)

Comment: Similarly, if you have left over rolled roofing (basically, it's roof shingle material, but as a roll), you can put that down over the whole thing, but if it's in an area that gets too hot, it can break down and the aggregte loosen ... hopefully, that won't be an issue as it's in a shady area.  I've also seen people just nail down leftover roof shingles on stairs, and it might work in place of the specialty strips in a pinch.

Comment: With the paint, you can get non-slip additives (pumice or sand), but to avoid constant mixing of the paint, you can sprinkle it on the surface after you get the first coat of paint down (and still wet).  Work it in with a roller, and then give it a good second coat.

Comment: @Joe: I wouldn't think shingles would hold up well under foot traffic, how long do the shingles last?

Comment: @Tester101 : In the location I saw them installed (stairs into a temporary office trailer), they had to replace 'em about once a year.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I've ordered some tape and will give that a try.  The paint-with-sand idea is my backup plan if the tape doesn't stay stuck.

Comment: Rememeber to apply it to a dry(waterproof) and clean surface.

Comment: I used the tape and it did not work. I wanted my wood ramp to be safe for the winter for us elderly & our animals. The first frost, they were popping up and my husband fell down onto the concrete sidewalk. And all 3 dogs have tripped to...Tried nailing them down but the area where there is no nails, it pops up. Very upset about it. Carpenters are the ones that said it would work. So I wanted to let others know my experience. Not good on tape.

Comment: So sorry to hear this. When you say popping up? Is the tape glued down to dry surface? Is it outdoor grade? What is the temp? -10? Sorry for all questions but there may be some unknown variables causing a problem.

Comment: Oh you used strips not tape. What lengths did you use? If it gets really cold they may not be suitable on very long lengths without expansion gaps

Answer (score 2):

Paint mixed with sand does not give enough roughness to the surface.  I took a fall 2 year ago on such a surface.  I am going to try the #10 non-skid Rustoleum paint.

Answer (score 0):

Use truck bedliner it has some aggregate in it and it will seal the wood.  you could also add a little more aggregate to it for some more grip.